# Pinescript Strategy Error when trying to sell

Tags: debugging, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

As you can see in my snap shot of my code below I have a buy and sell signal. I am trying to add this to my chart to back test and it does my initial buy but then it will never sell. I am not sure why because I have a similar script doing the same thing but it sells back and forth just fine when back testing. I have tested my sell signal buy seeing if a line will pop up on the graph when it is supposed to and it does so my code for that works fine. Something is wrong with the backrest portion though. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
buy = (crossover(z100,c100) and z100>f100 and trend>reg or crossover(z100,f100) and z100>c100 and trend>reg) ? 50 : 7.5
plot(buy, title="buy", color=color.blue)
sell = (crossunder(z100,c100) and z100<f100 or crossunder(z100,f100) and z100<c100) ? 50 : 7.5
plot(sell, title="sell", color=color.red)
shares = 10000/close
// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
FromMonth = input(defval = 10, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 24, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2017)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 12, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 25, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 2017)

// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false // create function "within window of time"
strategy.entry("buy", shares, when = window() and buy)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
strategy.close("sell", when = window() and sell)
```

Answer (score 2):

Candidate to problems in your code (assuming v4):

1) According to the reference manual (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4), you need to inform `strategy.close` the same ID of the open trade you're trying to close, "buy", in this case, as follows:

```
strategy.close("buy", when = window() and sell)
```

2) If the above does not fix the issue, try evaluating the expression for the `when` condition before calling `strategy.entry` an `strategy.close`, assigning the result to a variable and then referencing this variable in the `when` parameter.

Comment: That is correct! Thanks, that fixed it. However, it is buying on every single time bar now. Any chance you see why it is doing that? I have little spikes in my chart that show where my code actually wants it to buy and sell but for whatever reason it is buying and selling every single period.

Comment: Your "buy" and "sell" variables are always either 50 or 7.5. Therefore, they are considered TRUE always. If your're in the condition that window() also gives a TRUE, then indeed an entry and a close will happen at every single bar